# Java Regular Expression Not Finding My Char Class

Tags: java, android, regex

Very simply, idParser as seen below is not finding the number in my passedUrl string. 
Here is the LogCat out for the Lod.d's:

```
01-05 11:27:48.532: D/WEBVIEW_REGEX(29447): Parsing: http://mymobisite.com/cat.php?id=33
01-05 11:27:48.532: D/WEBVIEW_REGEX(29447): idParse: No Matches Found.
```

annnnd heres the block of trouble.

```
Log.d("WEBVIEW_REGEX", "Parsing: "+passableUrl.toString());
Matcher idParser = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1}").matcher(passableUrl);
if(idParser.groupCount() > 0)
    Log.d("WEBVIEW_REGEX", "idParse: " + idParser.group());
else Log.d("WEBVIEW_REGEX", "idParse: No Matches Found.");
```

note, this is me getting a bit sloppy now, I've tried a bunch of different syntaxes (all verified working at http://www.regextester.com/index2.html on all three modes ) and I've even looked up the documentation ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html). This is starting to get on my final nerve. 
using

```
.find()
```

instead of group() stuff just yields "false" ... Can someone help me to understand why i cant get this regular expression to work?

Cheers!

Comment: Your regex is really convoluted... `\d{1,5}` has the same effect!

Comment: `System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\d{1,5}")        .matcher("http://mymobisite.com/cat.php?id=33").find());` --> prints `true` here...

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark you probably meant `.matches()`, unfortunately Java misnames its `.matches()` methods -- they try and match the whole input, which contradicts with the very definition of regex matching

Comment: So to repeat the important thing: Why not just use `\d+`? Is there a restriction on the length or did you just not know about the existence of `+`?

Comment: Well, even if the convoluted regex (copy/pasted as is), a matcher here returns true. Are you _sure_ you use `java.util.regex`?

Comment: @fge absolutely im using java.util.regex, i have never actually used any of the 3rd party offerings before. In fact im not even NEW to regex in Java, but this one just gave me all sorts of headaches for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `groupCount()` doesn't do what you think it does. You should instead use `idParser.find()`. Like this:

```
if(idParser.find())
    Log.d("WEBVIEW_REGEX", "idParse: " + idParser.group());
else Log.d("WEBVIEW_REGEX", "idParse: No Matches Found.");
```

You could also simplify the pattern a bit, using `\d{1,5}` instead:

```
Matcher idParser = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,5}").matcher(passableUrl);
```

---

Full example:

```
String passableUrl = "http://mymobisite.com/cat.php?id=33";
Matcher idParser = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,5}").matcher(passableUrl);
if (idParser.find())
    System.out.println("idParse: " + idParser.group());
else 
    System.out.println("idParse: No Matches Found.");
```

Outputs:

```
idParse: 33
```

Comment: Quote from the question: `.find()` ... just yields "false".

Comment: This ended up working. Ultiamtely i did end up just swapping out the regex for `("\\d{1,5}")` like in the example and things started working a-ok. Im still curious why NO OTHER regex i had worked before (stuff like `"[0-9]{1,5}"` was yielding absolutely nothing for results), and like i said, i always check my regex with regextester v2.

Answer (score 1):

There are no `( )` braces hence zero groups.

All groups are numbered from left to right with a starting `(`. Matcher.group(1) would be the first group. Matcher.group() is the entire match. You need `find()` to move to the first match. Others already indicated there are simpler patterns, like `"\\d+$"`, a string ending with at least one digit.

Comment: Yes, that is part of the problem, but then OP says `.find()` on the matcher returns false -- and this defies logic

Comment: @fge The pattern works (in Java 7). For a moment I wondered if he had an other vertical bar sign, or would bind `|` tighter than a char class sequence: `"\d\d\d\d(\d|\d)\d\d(\d|\d)\d\(\d|\d)"` = 10 digits.